# HTML form not working as expected

Tags: html, forms, parameters

I have a form in a navigation bar. When I type something and click enter, I just obtain the page of this URL /html/sphider/search.php and not /html/sphider/search.php?query=something&search=1 as normally I should have.

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/html/sphider/search.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <input type="image" src="../images/search.png" name="btn" alt="search">
        <input type="hidden" name="search" value="1">
      </form>
```

Does anyone know why the parameters are not passed correctly to the search page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a POST request, not a GET request.  POST sends the data transparently through, while GET sends the data using the URL as you noted in your question.  Set method="get"

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/html/sphider/search.php" method="GET">
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using POST. For Post url will not include query value. Use Get insted POST. If you want to use POST then try this.

```
$_POST["search"];
```

This will be value of search

Answer (score 1):

Your action tells your form to post all data to "/html/sphider/search.php" path.

And within this script, you should reach your $_POST data. Like $_POST['name']

See more about PHP Requests from [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)